# How to share video to facebook as well as your own video player embeded?

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, flash-builder, flash

Hi i have a little problem sharing video on facebook with my own video palyer. How to do that properly also i am using Open Graph in facebook but no luck please give me some suggestions. thanks